# Extended class's constuctor get called twice

Tags: java, constructor

For the following code, the result is

> I am in B, value is 0
>   I am in B, value is 44
>   22

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        P b = new B();
        System.out.println(b.a);
    }

    static class P {
        public int a = 11;

        public P() {
            a = 22;
            diplay();
        }

        public void diplay() {
            System.out.println("I am in P, value is " + a);
        }
    }

    static class B extends P {
        int a = 33;

        public B() {
            a = 44;
            diplay();
        }

        public void diplay() {
            System.out.println("I am in B, value is " + a);
        }
    }
}
```

First, why does the constructor get called twice?
Why is `b.a` the value `22`?
Finally, why is the first `a` the value `0`?

Comment: why are you classes `static`

Comment: @ScaryWombat nothing to do with static or not.

Comment: I did not say it was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever you don't provide an explicit call to a superclass constructor, the Java compiler inserts an implicit call to the default superclass constructor for you (no arguments).  It's as if your `B` constructor was really:

```
public B() {
    super();
    a = 44;
    diplay();
}
```

The call to the superclass constructor calls the `P` constructor, which calls `diplay`.  The object is really a `B`, so with polymorphism, `B`'s `diplay` method is called.

*At this point, you have **leaked** your subclass instance, because it's not fully constructed yet.*  Because of this, `B`'s variable `a`, which hides `P`'s variable `a`, has not been initialized yet, so it still has its default value, `0`.

Then the superclass `P` constructor completes, and the rest of the `B` constructor runs, which also calls `diplay`.  This call sees the initialized `44` value.

The constructor is not called twice; the subclass constructor `B` is implicitly calling the superclass constructor `P`, and both constructors call `diplay`.

Back in `main`, you reference the field `a`, but the reference is on a variable of type `P`.  There is no field polymorphism, so even though the object is a `B` at runtime, the value of `P`'s `a` is retrieved, which was initialized to `22`.

This code shows why it's generally not a good idea to

1. leak `this` object instance before the constructor finishes, and
2. intentionally declare variables in a subclass with the same name as in the superclass.

Answer (score 1):

First, constructor of parent class `class P` is called. It then calls `diplay()`. Because you are creating instance of `class B` `B::diplay()` is called printing `I am in B, value is 0` because variable `a` which is defined in `B` is only initialized with default value 0 and `a = 33` is not yet executed. After that `a = 33` is executed, then constructor of `B` is executed and `I am B, value 44` is printed.
Here is the order of all those invocations:

> The order of calls is the following:
>
> 1.Static blocks* of the superclass
>
> 2.Static blocks* of the class
>
> 3.Non-static blocks* of the superclass
>
> 4.Constructor of the superclass
>
> 5.Non-static blocks* of the class
>
> 6.Constructor of the class

https://javacertificationroadmap.com/class-initialization-and-inheritance/